# AngularJS custom directive initial loading not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

You can see the [working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/KT6Zd/4/) - or should I say, non-working example.

Basically, I'm trying to make a custom directive called `yesno-group`. It is a shortcut to do this over and over:

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-model="checkboxField" btn-radio="true">Yes</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-model="checkboxField" btn-radio="false">No</button>
</div>
```

And here is my `yesno-group` directive:

```
myApp.directive('yesnoGroup', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            field: '=',
            buttonClass: '@'
        },
        replace: true,
        template:   '<div class="btn-group">' +
                    '    <button type="button" class="{{buttonClass}}" ng-model="field" btn-radio="true">Yes</button>' +
                    '    <button type="button" class="{{buttonClass}}" ng-model="field" btn-radio="false">No</button>' +
                    '</div>'
    };
});
```

The problem is, **`yesno-group` does not show the value on the initial load.** But once you start changing the value, it gets synchronized with the ngModel field.

What am I missing?

Also, how can I make the yesno-group to accept `ng-model` and use it instead of `field`? I got that from [JsFiddle-Examples](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/JsFiddle-Examples) - [currency input](http://jsfiddle.net/odiseo/dj6mX/), but wish to use `ng-model` unless it is a big hassle.

Thank you!

Comment: To have `ng-model` instead of `field` is straighforward. Just do: (1) replace in your isolate scope definition `field: '='` with `ngModel: '='` (2) in your template you write `ng-model="ngModel"` and (3) when using the directive you do `<div yesno-group ng-model="checkboxField" ...` instead of `field="checkboxField"`

Comment: @ThalisKalfigkopoulos Thank you that works. I thought I tried that but probably was confused with other issues.

Comment: Well what you want to read up on is using the ngModelController by "require"-ing it in a directive - not simply having an attribute named 'ngModel'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use ng-class, not class.

http://jsfiddle.net/KT6Zd/12/

```
myApp.directive('yesnoGroup', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            field: '=',
            buttonClass: '@'
        },
        replace: true,
        template:   '<div class="btn-group">' +
                    '    <button type="button" ng-class="buttonClass" ng-model="field" btn-radio="true">Yes</button>' +
                    '    <button type="button" ng-class="buttonClass" ng-model="field" btn-radio="false">No</button>' +
                    '</div>'
    };
});
```